# Is there a quick way to display values at addresses held in registers and to show the name of that register?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I am working on my first assembly assignment and it would be very helpful if I could use a command like

```
display (char*) (%rsp)
```

to show me the dereferenced value of %rsp in a format like,

(char*)(%rsp) = "here is a string"

and have it remain on the screen through all subsequent steps.

Is something like this possible, and if not, is there any faster way to do it than

```
i r rsp
0x000000001234
display (char*) 0x000000001234
```

Comment: Have you tried `display (char*)$rsp`?

Comment: Oh so a $ dereferences?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `$` is a variable and register prefix. `gdb` knows to show you a `(char*)` as a string though. Also, you can force any format you want, see `help display`.

Comment: Thanks.  One more question, is it possible to auto display all registers at once?

Comment: You can switch to a register layout. See `help layout`.

Comment: I'm still confused by this. If I type "print $rsp" does that print the address stored in %rsp or the value that %rsp points to?

Comment: That shows the address in `%rsp`.